# OBJC swizzling fails to spoof the method

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to swizzle/spoof the test.func method to be the test.funcs method, I read the whole Apple documentary about it but for some reason it fails when I try to spoof a class method +(void). Does anyone know why and if yes can you help me by solving the problem!

```
@implementation test

+(void)func {
    NSLog(@"Hello");
}

+(void)funcs {
    NSLog(@"HI");
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [test func];
// Prints Hello

    SEL originalSelector = @selector(func);
    SEL overrideSelector = @selector(funcs);

    Class Originalclass = [test class];
    Class OverRideClass = [test class];


    Method originalMethod =  class_getClassMethod(Originalclass, originalSelector);
    Method overrideMethod = class_getClassMethod(OverRideClass, overrideSelector);

    if (class_addMethod(Originalclass, originalSelector, method_getImplementation(overrideMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(overrideMethod))) {
        class_replaceMethod(OverRideClass, overrideSelector, method_getImplementation(originalMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod));
    } else {
        method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, overrideMethod);
    }

    [test func];
// Prints Hello but should print Hi

}


@end
```